# What performance gains Job Scheduler gives over startService()

Tags: android, performance, android-jobscheduler

From `Oreo`, a service will not work if the app is not in foreground, but we can use `JobSchedular` to perform background operations.

Then what's really is the difference between `JobScheduler` and `startService()`, and why android is supporting `JobSchedular` over `startService()` for background operations from `oreo`.

I can still `Schedule` tons of `Jobs` from backround, and it will also effect battery performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> From Oreo, a service will not work if the app is not in foreground

Yes, it will. It merely needs to be a foreground service.

> Then what's really is the difference between JobScheduler and startService()

`startService()` is immediate. A job scheduled with `JobScheduler` is not. `JobScheduler` can postpone the work until a later time, when other work needs to be done, to minimize the amount of time that power is consumed (for CPU, for WiFi, for mobile data, etc.).

Also, `startService()` always happens. A job scheduled with `JobScheduler` might not. You can put criteria on the job (e.g., requires a network connection), and the job will only be run if the criteria are met.

> and why android is supporting JobSchedular over startService() for background operations from oreo.

Power consumption, mostly, as far as I can tell.

> I can still Schedule tons of Jobs from backround, and it will also effect battery performance.

Yes, but Google has a much better API for being able to control that in the future. If developers abuse `JobScheduler`, future versions of Android can further rate-limit jobs, expand Doze mode for jobs, and so on.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare, one more question, will this effect Firebase Push Notification, do we need to make changes there as well, or Firebase will handle that for oreo.

Answer (score 2):

From Android developers website:

> The framework will be intelligent about when it executes jobs, and
>   attempt to batch and defer them as much as possible. Typically if you
>   don't specify a deadline on a job, it can be run at any moment
>   depending on the current state of the JobScheduler's internal queue.
>
> While a job is running, the system holds a wakelock on behalf of your
>   app. For this reason, you do not need to take any action to guarantee
>   that the device stays awake for the duration of the job.

When you start a background service it is running even if the app is in the background, thus it uses resources. With `JobScheduler` the resources are only allocated and used for a particular job, and are freed when it's done.

Comment: Thanks @Andrej, Will this effect Firebase Push Notification, do we need to make changes there as well, or Firebase will handle that.